# How to create anti-aliased text on a Bitmap with ExtTextOut?

Tags: c#, fonts, bitmap, gdi, antialiasing

In my WinForm app I draw into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. I create fonts from a LOGFONT and draw using the GDI function ExtTextOutW. However the output is terrible. It has bad jaggies and looks like the antialiaser was on LSD. Reading around this seems a common issue - is there a resolution?

If I use:

```
lf.lfQuality = FontQuality.NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY
```

when I create the font then the horrible jaggies go away but of course there is no antialiasing.

Is there a way to create smooth text in a Bitmap with ExtTextOutW?

Comment: Have you tried FontQuality.CLEARTYPE_QUALITY? (this may not make any difference from NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY, depending on the font)

Comment: If I use FontQuality.CLEARTYPE_QUALITY I get the jagged effect as if anti-aliasing has just gone wrong (almost as if it has picked the wrong pixel colour).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but a bit tricky and it can't have transparent background.
You will need to:

1. Create in-memory bitmap buffer that is compatible with display device context (IntPtr.Zero handle)
2. Fill the buffer background with solid color or other background
3. Render the text into the memory bitmap
4. Copy from in-memory bitmap to image device context (BitBlt)

See [GDI text rendering to image](http://theartofdev.com/2014/01/12/gdi-text-rendering-to-image/) for more details.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the bitblt (or similar) to make the effect of text without a solid background?

Comment: yep, you can bitblt the existing background into the in-memory buffer, render on it and then bitblt everything back. I do that for transparent text rendering [here](http://theartofdev.com/2013/10/24/transparent-text-rendering-with-gdi/) (DrawTransparentText method).